# SQL Group BY and Having Count to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Struggling to Convert this SQL query to LINQ

```
select * from Jobs J
JOIN (
select JobId from JobAttributes where Attribute IN ('X','Y','Z')
group by JobId
having count(distinct Attribute) =3) Ids 
ON J.ID = Ids.JobId
```

JobId and Attribute are Columns in JobAttributes table.

I currently have this. But I am failing to Join.

```
from aj in db.dbJobAttributes
where attributeList.Contains(aj.Attribute)
group new { aj } by new { aj.JobId } into grp
where grp.Count(aj.Attribute) == 3
select aj
```

Comment: So, what did you actually try with LINQ? Please [edit] your question and include enough code for us to be able to help you. Also include the library you are using to transform to SQL (is it LinQ to SQL, Entity Framework, which version?)

Comment: I was able to get 2nd part of the query done. but am failing to JOIN         
from aj in db.dbJobAttributes
where attributeList.Contains(aj.Attribute)
group new { aj } by new { aj.JobId } into grp
where grp.Count(aj.Attribute) == 3
select aj

Comment: That's great, if you can [edit] (notice that [edit] is a link) your question and include that code, we can help you from there

Answer (score 0):

```
 IQueryable<long> selectedJobIds = from aj in db.dbJobAttributes
                                              where attributeList.Contains(aj.Attribute)
                                              group aj by aj.JobId into grp
                                              where grp.Count() == attributeList.Count()
                                              select grp.Key;

            dbjobs = from j in db.dbJobs
                     join sjId in selectedJobIds
                     on j.ID equals sjId
                     select j;
```